# SSRS error. Browser doesn't load

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, superuser

I want to run SSRS reports on Internet Explorer browser. Link I use is http://ServerName/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ViewMode=List
But when I run it, it doesn't load, it stays for a while as if it is loading. What can be the reason? Reports in browser worked about half a year without any problem. I understand that this information may not be enough, ask and I'll try to answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the issue i.e. what doesn't load? Is it the list of reports, the reports themselves, the report is stuck with a 'loading' message?

Comment: Page, where report folders are located. Page is in loading status. I've waited for a half an hour, but it was still loading

Comment: I'd suggest that this isn't a programming related issue and more of a setup related issue. Your question may get more noticed at SuperUser.

Comment: I've to add "SuperUser" tag, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are browsing in IE, make sure you are running your browser as Admin.  Report manager does not play well with IE unless in Admin mode...